# why my two graph of d3.js is not combined in the single page?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have made two separate graph on separate page of Bar and pie chart respectively and now i wanted to combine this two graph in the single page so that I can have a dashboard. but when i start to combine to two graph in the main page its not happening and they overlap of each other.
Code:
https://github.com/Mustafa2911/d3-design/blob/main/combine.html
Combine file contain: Code of both pie and bar chart.
Bar file contain: Code of bar chart.
Pie chart contain: Code of pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this with your code.
Scroll to see the bar graph axis.

*NOTE*: The bar graph data will not be available ∵ it is from the demo1.csv file in your repository.

Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <!-- Load d3.js -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #my_dataviz {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var width = 800
    height = 450
    margin = 40
    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin
    // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
    // Create dummy data
    var data = {
      Corporation_Tax: 15,
      Income_Tax: 15,
      Customs: 5,
      Union_Excise_Duties: 7,
      Good_and_Service_tax: 16,
      Non_tax_Revenue: 5,
      Non_Dept_Capital_Receipt: 2,
      Borrowings_Liabilities: 35
    }
    // set the color scale
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])
      .range(d3.schemeSet1);
    // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
    var pie = d3.pie()
      .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })
    var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))
    // The arc generator
    var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.5) // This is the size of the donut hole
      .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
    // Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
    var outerArc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
      .outerRadius(radius * 0.9)
    // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
    svg
      .selectAll('allSlices')
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return (color(d.data.key))
      })
      .attr("stroke", "white")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
    // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
    svg
      .selectAll('allPolylines')
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter()
      .append('polyline')
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr('points', function(d) {
        var posA = arc.centroid(d) // line insertion in the slice
        var posB = outerArc.centroid(d) // line break: we use the other arc generator that has been built only for that
        var posC = outerArc.centroid(d); // Label position = almost the same as posB
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 // we need the angle to see if the X position will be at the extreme right or extreme left
        posC[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1); // multiply by 1 or -1 to put it on the right or on the left
        return [posA, posB, posC]
      })
    // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
    svg
      .selectAll('allLabels')
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .text(function(d) {
        console.log(d.data.key);
        return d.data.key
      })
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
        pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
      })
      .style('text-anchor', function(d) {
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
        return (midangle < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end')
      })
  </script>

  <style>
    #my_dataviz {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50%;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="my_dataviz_es"></div>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 40,
        left: 160
      },
      width = 460,
      height = 400;
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz_es")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    // Parse the Data
    d3.csv("demo1.csv", function(data) {
      // Add X axis
      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 550000])
        .range([0, width]);
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
        .style("text-anchor", "end");
      // Y axis
      var y = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, height])
        .domain(data.map(function(d) {
          return d.Country;
        }))
        .padding(.1);
      svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      //Bars
      svg.selectAll("myRect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", x(0))
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.Country);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return x(d.Value);
        })
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
        .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
      // .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Country); })
      // .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Value); })
      // .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      // .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Value); })
      // .attr
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**: See here - https://codepen.io/KZJ/pen/rNpqvdq?editors=1011 - for changes made reg. the below comment

> what if I want to have my bar chart at the top and on right side i want to have my pie chart

Changed -

a) Both charts were using the same name *'svg'* to d3.select() the divs. This caused the charts to overlap.

b) Modified width, height, transform, and added some border CSS - only for demonstration purposes - It can be removed/edited as required.

FYR this is how it looks now -
[image]

Comment: its working thanks, but what if I want to have my bar chart at the top and on right side i want to have my pie chart, How can i do this

Comment: I've edited the above answer & added a link to codepen as well...